# AJAX results to a <p> in stead of an <input>

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm learning AJAX via online tutorial and I'm trying to play with the code.

Following is the code form the tutorial:

```
<body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function ajaxFunction(){
var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

try{
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e){
            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
// Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        document.myForm.time.value = ajaxRequest.responseText;
    }
}
ajaxRequest.open("POST", "serverTime.php", true);
ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}

</script>

<form name='myForm'>
Name: <input type='text' onChange="ajaxFunction();" name='username' /> <br />
<!--  *******  this is what I want to work with: ****-->   <input type='text' name='time' />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I wanted the results to print to a simple `<p>` tag instead of an `<input>`. I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
<p name="time"></p>
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Based on the answers below, I changed the code to:

```
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
                var txtNode = document.createTextNode(ajaxRequest.responseText);
                document.getElementById("time").appendChild(txtNode);
    }
```

and

```
<p id="time"></p>
```

I still can't get it to work.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paragraph element can't have a `name` attribute, you need to use an `id` instead. This means you should also use `document.getElementById("time")` instead of `document.myForm.time`.

Edit your JavaScript:

```
if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {
    var txtNode = document.createTextNode(ajaxRequest.responseText);
    document.getElementById("time").appendChild(txtNode);
}
```

And your HTML:

```
<p id="time"></p>
```

Comment: Note that my solution _appends_ text to the body of the paragraph. This means if you get more than one text response then they'll all be appended together. If you don't want that, then use `innerHTML` as in @vdua's answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I still having trouble.  Can you pls have a look at my EDIT in the question and tell me where I'm going wrong?  Many thanks.

Comment: @dwstein - It's working fine for me. You know that you have to edit the `name` field to trigger the AJAX request, right? (That's what the `onChange` event in the text field is doing.)

Comment: Thanks!  that finally works.  I don't know what the problem was.

Comment: I see you changed form innerHTML to textConnect.  Was that the problem?  If so, why would that be a problem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26572/discussion-between-dwstein-and-daowen)

Answer (score 1):

you can only access input,select and textarea tags in a form by there name and not the p tag (or for matter any other tag). You can't even have the name attribute in p tag.

```
document.myForm.time.value = ajaxRequest.responseText; 
// time should be a input tag with name time in order for this code to work
```

Instead of this do

```
<p id="time"></p>
```

and in your javascript code

```
document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
```

Comment: `<p>` elements don't have a `value` attribute. You could use `innerHTML` or `innerText`, but I'm not sure how standard either of those are. _Edit:_ Ah, you just fixed it—never mind.

Comment: @dwstein - Yup, it's the same _id_, so You could set a style rule for your paragraph using `#time`. You can also use _ids_ as anchors, so if your URL is `w.x.y/z/` you can link directly to that paragraph via `w.x.y/z/#time`.

Comment: Does this mean that any elements with the same `id` will be effected by the AJAX object?

Comment: @dwstein - It's illegal to define two elements with the same `id`, so that behavior is probably undefined. My guess is that the DOM engine will just find the first one (or maybe the last one).

Comment: @DaoWen 
innerHTML is a standard but has some security issues when content is obtained from users. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML#Security_considerations
which proves your solution is the better one.

Comment: @vdua - I guess I was just conflating `innerHTML` with `innerText` (which I'm pretty sure is the non-standard one). Thanks for the clarification! Also, based on that link, it looks like the best answer is actually to use [`element.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.textContent?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Felement.textContent) to set the text.